# terminal Plugin in sublime text3 can't open the lastest iterm2

Tags: sublimetext3, iterm2

terminal Plugin in sublime text3 can open the iTerm2 of old version, but recently when my iTerm2 update , terminal plugin can't open now , and my setting like this [setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Veayw.png)

Answer (score 0):

iTerm2's applescript was changed, so the plugin probably needs to be updated. Docs at https://iterm2.com/applescript.html